# Auto layout acting weird with collection view cell

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have a view inside a collection view cell, and simply want the view to grow/shrink with the collection view cell. I add constraints that work perfectly if the collection view cell was just a UIView, but for some reason it does not work. I'm suspecting it might be a bug with collection view cells, anyone tried this before?

Here is a screenshot of the setup. Super simple, red view inside collection view cell, I just want it to resize the same way the collection view cell does.

[image]

Comment: What actually happens that you find improper?

Comment: I start dragging the corner of the cell, and the red box resizes in a really weird way, like half of if goes off in the top left direction.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem.  I think it's a bug in Xcode.  Go to http://bugreport.apple.com and open a ticket.

You can work around it by going to the “Resolve Auto Layout Issues” popup and choosing “Update Frames” under the “All Views in Collection View Cell” item:

[image: collection view cell resize bug]

Comment: I have created a bug report and attached the animated gif you've created, thx for that.